# How do I change text in another div using OnClick function in jvectormap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, onclick, jvectormap

I'm using [this map plugin](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/#maps).

When I click on each country, I want to change the text in a div called `#content`, which is invisible by default.

I planned to make it by using a different div called `#apDiv3`.

Content after first click should stay visible until you click another country.

I'm using this code but nothing happens:

```
$(function () {
    $('#example-map-1').vectorMap({
        backgroundColor: ('#1d1e21'),
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
        hoverColor: ('#4f1d1e'),
        onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
            if(code === 'ca') {
                event(function () {
                    $("#content").replaceWith($("#apDiv3"))
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
    onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
        if(code === 'ca') {
            $("#content").replaceWith($("#apDiv3"))
        }
    });
```

Not entirely sure what you were going for with the event thing, but you don't need it.